# $u\in L^\infty$ implies that the set of the limits point of $u(x)$ as $x\to +\infty$ is non empty. Why?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $u\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^n)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
During class, it has been said that it implies that the set of accumulation points of $u(x)$ as $x\to +\infty$ (or equivalently as $x\to -\infty$) is non empty.

Anyone could please explain me why that is true?

Thank you in advance!

$\bf{EDIT:}$ I suspect that something was stated wrong. I think that it was referred to "set of limits points as $u(x)$ as $x\to \infty$". In that case, does $u\in L^\infty$ imply that it is not empty?

Comment: Do you know the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) in relation to sequential compactness?

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes, but how it is related in this case with the set of the accumulation points of $u$?

Comment: Well, before that, how exactly do you want to define the accumulation points at infinity of a function $u : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I apologize, "at infinity" had no sense. I have removed it from the question.

Comment: That part didn't much matter.  The question still stands: Before we get to an explanation, how do you want to define an accumulation point of $u(x)$ as $x \to \infty$?  I would tend to define it in this context as the set of subsequential limits.  Is that how you want to define it?

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes, it is the case.

Comment: I still have no idea what is meant by an accumulation point of $u(x)$. $u(x)$ is merely an element of $\Bbb R^n$, and can only be thought to accumulate at itself. It might make more sense to ask for accumulation points of the function $u$ (**not** $u(x)$) but it’s still quite unclear to me what you mean, even after Moehring’s comment

Comment: @FShrike I suspect that it was stated wrong. I think that it was referred to "set of limits points as $u(x)$ as $x\to \infty$. In that case, does $u\in L^\infty$ imply that it is not empty?

Comment: … this now makes less sense to me. Please define the problem

Answer (score 2):

You haven’t stated the problem in a way that’s clear to me. So this answer is based on a *guess* of the intended meaning.

> An accumulation point at infinity of a function $u:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$ is a point $x\in\Bbb R^n$ where there is a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset\Bbb R$ tending to positive infinity with $\lim_{n\to\infty}u(y_n)=x$.

For example, with $u=\sin$ this interpretation suggests the accumulation points at infinity are precisely $[-1,1]$.

In this case, an essentially bounded $u$ shall always have at least one such point. There is a subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$ with null complement and a bound $M>0$ with $u(A)\subseteq[-M,M]^n$. The right hand side is sequentially (and topologically) compact. In fact, I believe the conclusion is true for any integrable function $u$ too. If $A:=u^{-1}[-1,1]^n$ has $\mu(\Bbb R\setminus A)=+\infty$ then $u$ would obviously fail to be integrable. So $\Bbb R\setminus A$ has finite measure.

In both cases ($u$ integrable or $u$ essentially bounded):

$A$ must contain a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ that tends to positive infinity. By sequential compactness, we have - potentially passing to a subsequence - that $(u(y_n))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is convergent.

$A$ must then be nonempty, so there is some $y_1\in A$. If there existed no $y_2\in A$ with $y_2>1+y_1$, that would imply $\Bbb R\setminus A\supseteq(1+y_1,\infty)$ which contradicts the finiteness of measure. Thus there is such a $y_2\in A$. The same argument inductively provides a $y_3\in A$ with $y_3>1+y_2$, a $y_4\in A$ with $y_4>1+y_3$, etc., producing a strictly increasing and divergent sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subseteq A$.

Comment: FShrike, thank you for your answer. I find it very clear, except for one point. Why do you need to introduce $A\subset\mathbb{R}$? Why you can not say that $u(t)\in [-M, M]^n$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: Also, could you please add some details concerning that $A$ contains a sequence converging to positive infinity? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @C.Bishop Because an *essentially* bounded function need not be bounded. E.g. $$u:\Bbb R\ni x\mapsto\begin{cases}0&x\neq 0\\+\infty&x=0\end{cases}\in\overline{\Bbb R}$$Is measurable and essentially bounded but it is obviously not bounded.